# Swift_Mailter addCc for multiple email addresses

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have the following code to send email using symfony2 swift_mailer

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('tets')
                ->setFrom(array('request@reqa.com' => 'Test Mail'))
                ->addTo('test@test.com')
                ->addCc('test@te.com')
                ->addCc('test1@test1.com')
                ->addCc('test2@test2.com')
                ->setBody($html, 'text/html');
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

My problem is i am loading addCc email addresses from database, Therefore is there any method to addCC email addresses by seperating them by , like this
              ->addCc('test2@test2.com,test4@test4.com')

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use `setCC` directly ( [documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#setting-cc-recipients) ) ...

```
$message->setCc(array(
  'person1@example.org',
  'person2@otherdomain.org' => 'Person 2 Name',
  'person3@example.org',
  'person4@example.org',
  'person5@example.org' => 'Person 5 Name'
));
```

... or loop over your collection of entites and execute `addCC` for each of them.

```
$receipients = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("...")->findBy(array(".." => ".."));

foreach ($receipients as $receipient) {
   $message->addCC($receipient->getMail());
}

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

... or if you only have the `,`-separated string with the cc adresses available just `explode` the string to an array. and afterwards loop over the array elements or pass the array directly to `setCC` as shown above.